# Executing oracle query to database at other server via shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

I have an image server (A) and a database server (B). I have to process files in image server via a shell script after doing analysing query result from B.

I need help in connecting writing a script for connecting to server B database and executing the query and deliver the result in a variable. The script will run at server A. Oracle is used as database

Answer (score 0):

Generally Executing Oracle-SQL in Shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

sqlplus -s $user/$pass@$db<<EOFSQL
    # your sql here
    quit
EOFSQL
```

Example of getting SQL-Script-Output (including error Messages) to a variable:

```
result=$( { sqlplus -s $db_user/$db_pwd@$db @$qry  2>&4 ; } 4>&1)
```

$qry would by the path to your sql-Script, if not using heredoc.

Comment: I tried it but oracle client is not installed in server where shell will run due to which an error comes which states that command not found. I have to do this in over 50 servers so I cant't install oracle client in them. 

Please suggest a solution without sqlplus.